# How to configure Cheetah on Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, cheetah

Is there a tutorial on how to configure Django and cheetah to print out simple text like hello world in variables or lists?

I'm trying to configure cheetah with Django or find instructions on how to or tutorials but without luck. I've already tried the cheetah docs Django module but it's much more going on

Plz little help

Comment: I released [`django-cheetahtemplate` 0.4.0](https://pypi.org/project/django-cheetahtemplate/0.4.0/) just a few days ago. Full disclosure: I'm the current maintainer of `Cheetah3` and the author of `django-cheetahtemplate`.

Comment: I saw the example but how to configure it...I mean e.g Cheetah.Django.render() is not valid

Comment: https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/django-cheetahtemplate/blob/f74b8cb61a7eb0f34e409fd4d3a37f5453653e7d/example/example/settings.py#L25 It's explained at the very pages https://pypi.org/project/django-cheetahtemplate/ and https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/django-cheetahtemplate#django-cheetahtemplate